# How to keep packages updated in vNext RC1 based on DNX SDK version?

Tags: asp.net-core

Across many projects in one solution, what is a way to keep packages up to date, based on targeted DNX SDK version? We recently updated to `1.0.0-rc1-update1`, but now we have to manually edit the `project.json` files and figure out what package versions are meant for our DNX SDK version. Is there a command or tool I can use to make this easier?

Answer (score 0):

There's no out of the box solution to pin/unpin/upgrade packages. You'll have to find/replace.

Another alternative, if you're okay with getting the latest versions of the packages from the feeds that you use, is to use star-versions:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Foo": "1.0.0-*",
        "Bar": "1.0.0-rc1-*"
    }
    ...
}
```

Upon restore, `Foo` and `Bar` will get the closest version (greater or equal) that matches the pattern.

This is great especially if you have packages that get upgraded multiple times per day/week and you don't want to change every project.json file when that happens.

PS: noticed that I didn't fully answer your question: there's no way to get "matching" versions for packages and DNX because the packages don't know about their compatibility with other packages/runtimes. At restore time you'll get an error if `dnu` cannot find a package that is at least the required version but it will not complain when it upgrades.

Comment: How is the "required version" defined?
And how do you handle libraries that go through major version changes, like `Newtonsoft.Json`? Based on your response, it seems like there is no possible answer, as there is no simple `dnu update` (or similar)